# fabric.js exporting as svg issue with circles

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

When importing circle objects and then exporting to svg, they become invisible paths. Am I doing something wrong or a bug?

```
  <path d="M 90 0 A 90 90 0 0 1 90 1.256933281983528e-12" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(1329.1 559.64) "/>
```

See fiddle example click export and see how the svg added manually is correct `<circle />`
http://jsfiddle.net/nwkdzss2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rounding problem. You have these paramaters in there:

```
  "startAngle":0,
  "endAngle":6.2831853071796,
```

They are interpreted as more than 2π, and for some reason, that flips the large angle flag (the fourth number after `A`) to false, and only the "short path" between the two points is drawn:

```
d="M 90 0 A 90 90 0 0 1 90 1.256933281983528e-12"
```

If you use a slightly smaller number for 2π,

```
  "startAngle":0,
  "endAngle":6.2831853,
```

the path data are interpreted to use the "long way".

```
d="M 90 0 A 90 90 0 1 1 90 -6.461627453714901e-7"
```

Leaving these parameters off completely would draw a circle primitive.